# A better way to pass values through url with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, variables, url

I am working on a Wordpress site that is using a form plugin. The plugin uses an unusual method to post the form values and does not seem to support a way to pass on any $POST or $GET variables. I.e. print_r on $POST returns an empty array. Strangely the plugin also "requires" the action of the form to be blank. Basically all it will do is redirect you to a "thank you page" after submitting the data.

I needed to pre-populate a singular field in a follow up form, so I got the idea of using javascript to pass the needed variable to the "thank you page" url which really leads to the follow up form. Normally this url is supposed to be hard coded as a hidden field in the form, but I decided to just create it on the fly. Since sadly I am more familiar with jQuery than js I decided to use it instead.

So anyway I got it to work using the following code, but have a feeling there is a better way, and fear there may be some unforeseen consequences to the way I am doing it.

```
$('#address').keyup(function () {
   string = this.value; //store value from address input field
   string = string.replace(/\s/g,"%20"); // Replace spaces 
   var url = "http://example.com/?page_id=156"; // url to thank you page 
   jQuery('#thankyou').html('<input type="hidden" name="thank_you_page" value="' + url  + '&property=' + string + '" type="text">');  // add the required hidden field to the form
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than injecting using jQuery. You could simplify and just add the hidden straight to the form with an ID.

eg

```
<form>
  <input id="thank_you_page_field" type="hidden" name="thank_you_page" value="" type="text">
</form>
```

then just use jquery to populate it.

eg

```
$('#address').keyup(function () {
   string = this.value; //store value from address input field
   string = string.replace(/\s/g,"%20"); // Replace spaces 
   var url = "http://example.com/?page_id=156"; // url to thank you page 
   url += '&property=' + string
   jQuery('#thank_you_page_field').val(url) // update the value.
 });
```

Also instead of

```
 string = string.replace(/\s/g,"%20"); // Replace spaces
```

try  encodeURIComponent()  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

with the final code possibly looking like this

```
$('#address').keyup(function () {
   var url = "http://example.com/?page_id=156"; // url to thank you page 
   url += '&property=' + this.value //append the value
   $('#thank_you_page_field').val(encodeURIComponent(url)) // update the value
 });
```

Comment: Nice. I had actually tried to use .val() but apparently was not implementing it correctly. I looked up the docs on encodeURI / encodeURIComponent. Thanks for pointing it out, it will be very useful in the future.